# JPA - There are no attributes for the ReportQuery

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have the below code snippet to get count of records, however when I execute I am getting the following

> Exception [EclipseLink-6088] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
>   Exception Description: There are no attributes for the ReportQuery.
>   Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Employees )

```
    private Integer countEmployees(EmployeesList<Employees> emp) {

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> countQ = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);

        Root<Employees> empCount = countQ.from(Employees.class);
        Join<Employees, Department> joinDept = 
            empCount.join(Employees_.deptId, JoinType.LEFT);

        List<Predicate> empListCount = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        Predicate empNameCount,empOrgCount;

        ......
        countQ.where(predicatesCount);
        ......

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified a where clause 'if' there is an EmpName, but nothing else.  You need to select something. Since you seem to want to count employees, you need to add the "select count(employee)" part of the query:

```
countQ.select(criteriaBuilder.count(empCount));
```

Comment: Learn what the Exceptions are trying to tell u makes the learning curve exponential